# unable to connect to the cli container

Tags: docker, hyperledger-fabric

I am following official Hyperledger Fabric documentation(Build your first network). When executing `docker exec -it cli bash`, it is not being executed. There is no response. I cannot use peer command.

`docker exec -it cli bash`, output:

```
root@e45419781222:/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer#
```

I cannot enter further commands and it doesn't show any errors. And when I try to use peer command from another terminal, it throws peer command not found.

I think it is not connected to cli container.

I am just starting out with hyperledger. I cannot identify the error and it seems there is no resources regarding this issue.

I expect to connect to the cli container.

Answer (score 0):

Try this command.

```
docker exec -it cli /bin/bash
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, very dumb mistake even for linux and fabric noobie. I realized you have to write command after "root@e45419781222:/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer#". I thought this was end of the execution. And peer command works form this rather than opening new terminal.